# Oracle 11g R2 Install Guide

Tags: windows, oracle, installation, oracle-11g

I have a need to install Oracle 11g R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have downloaded the two files from Oracle (win64_11gR2_database) and the client (win64_11gR2_client).  Does anyone have a guide or step by step to sucessfully setup Oracle?  My goal is to connect to the database from Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks

Comment: [Oracle 11g release 2 - Microsoft Windows Installation Guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=11&frame=#microsoft_windows_installation_guides)

Comment: [Oracle 11g step-by-step Installation Guide with Screenshots](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/oracle-11g-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-screenshots/)

Comment: When you install an Oracle Database then the client is always included. There is not need to install an extra Oracle client.